# How to call method by name using Kotlin Reflection?

Tags: kotlin, reflection

Is there any easy way to call method by name in Kotlin?

Something like:

```
val obj: Any
obj.invokeMethod("methodName", args...)
```

Comment: Why do you want to do this?  It's possible (using reflection), but it's not generally a good idea for normal application code, as it performs badly, is fragile, bypasses all type checking, can throw a variety of exceptions which should be handled, tends to be long-winded and hard to read, and defeats encapsulation and other security mechanisms .  (It's mainly for things like plug-ins, dependency-injection frameworks, and other tools.)

Comment: I need this for mapping actions from JSON to Kotlin code.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

try this:

```
obj::class.members.firstOrNull { it.name == "methodName" }?.call(argument1, argument2, ...)
```